# PHP GD color difference

Tags: colors, wamp, jpeg, gd, php-7

I'm using Wamp, PHP 7.1.9 and GD to resize a lot of images via Imagine library (which is not the problem because I have this also when I'm not using Imagine). Anyway, the colors of my images are slightly different after the resizing -- oversaturated.

Is this a common problem?

Here is my code, I'm using a CakePHP 3 Component to create multiples images from a single one to match with screen sizes (to load in srcset in html views) :

```
public function imagesSet($id){
    $this->Controller->autoRender = false;

    $Table = TableRegistry::get($this->Controller->Model_name);
    $entity = $Table->get($id);

    $file_path = WWW_ROOT.'/img/'.$this->Controller->Model_name.'/'.$entity->id.'/'.$entity->file;

    $ext = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = str_replace('.'.$ext,'',$entity->file);

    if(is_file($file_path)){

        foreach($this->Controller->widths as $width):
            //!\ THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
            $size = new \Imagine\Image\Box(200, 200);
            $mode = \Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;
            $imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();

            $new_file_path = WWW_ROOT.'/img/'.$this->Controller->Model_name.'/'.$entity->id.'/'.$filename.'_'.$width.'.'.$ext;

            $image = $imagine->open($file_path);
            $image->resize($image->getSize()->widen($width))->save($new_file_path);
        endforeach;
    }           
}
```

Edit : It seems that the difference in color is caused by a conversion of a CMYK image to a RGB image. Unfortunatly, GD can't convert CMYK to RGB without a significative change of color... And ImageMagick is a pain in the ass to install.

Comment: Show us the code and then someone may be able to help you

Comment: I edit my post with my code. Thanks for you anwser !